# Linking the vampir trace libraries in Cmake

Tags: cmake, libraries

I am having trouble linking the vampir trace libraries in Cmake. I tried to follow the code in http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=KpkR7xBIrapei6B9rI03NO7f-qo&cid=qbbSyBAI9cM&s=&browser=Default&fp=301524&mpundefined&projSelected=true#L0

I have in part of my CMake file:

```
set(VAMPIRTRACE_ROOT $HOME/Downloads/VampirTrace-5.14.4)
set(VAMPIRTRACE_LIBRARIES ${VAMPIRTRACE_ROOT}/vtlib/.libs/libvt.so)

include_directories(${VAMPIRTRACE_ROOT}/include)
add_definitions( -DVTRACE )

add_executable(ApplyingVtkMarchingCubes ApplyingVtkMarchingCubes.cxx)

target_link_libraries(ApplyingVtkMarchingCubes ${VAMPIRTRACE_LIBRARIES})
```

but when I do cmake and make, it can't recognize the header file #include "vt_user.h" still.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> set(VAMPIRTRACE_ROOT $HOME/Downloads/VampirTrace-5.14.4)

Are you trying to read environment variable HOME?
If so the right way to do it is:

> set(VAMPIRTRACE_ROOT $ENV{HOME}/Downloads/VampirTrace-5.14.4)

**PS** You can easily find such errors if you turn on compiler messages:

> set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)

And take a look at compiler line. It must look like this:

> g++ -I/Downloads/Vampir../include

but you expect:

> g++ -I/home/username/Downloads/Vampir../include